# An edge partitioning problem on cubic graphs

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity, algorithms, co.combinatorics

Hello everyone,

I already asked this question on the [TCS Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/an-edge-partitioning-problem-on-cubic-graphs), but it has not been resolved yet. Maybe readers of this forum will have other ideas or information, although I suspect that the sets of users of both places form a large intersection.

Has the complexity of the following problem been studied?

---

**Input**: a cubic (or $3$-regular) graph $G=(V,E)$, a natural upper bound $t$

**Question**: is there a partition of $E$ into $|E|/3$ parts of size $3$ such that the sum of the orders of the (nonnecessarily connected) corresponding subgraphs is at most $t$?

---

**Related work**

I found quite a few papers in the literature that prove necessary and/or sufficient conditions for the **existence** of a partition into some graphs containing three edges, which is somehow related, and some others on computational complexity matters of problems that intersect with the above (e.g. the partition must yield subgraphs isomorphic to $K_{1,3}$ or $P_4$, and no weight is associated with a given partition), but none of them dealt exactly with the above problem.

Listing all those papers here would be a bit tedious, but most of them either cite or are cited by [Dor and Tarsi](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/129712.129737).

A more closely related work is [this paper by Goldschmidt et al.](http://lyle.smu.edu/~olinick/olinickpapers/publications/sepp.pdf), who prove that the problem of edge partitioning a graph into parts containing AT MOST $k$ edges, in such a way that the sum of the orders of the induced subgraphs is at most $t$, is NP-complete, even when $k=3$. Another difference between their problem and the one I describe is that they do not allow subgraphs to be disconnected. Is it obvious that their problem remains NP-complete on cubic graphs, when we require strict equality w.r.t. $t$ and drop the connectivity constraint?

**Additional information**

I've tried some strategies that failed. More precisely, I found some counterexamples that prove that:

- maximising the number of triangles does not lead to an optimal solution; which I find somehow counter-intuitive, since triangles are those subgraphs with lowest order among all possible graphs on three edges;
- partitioning the graph into connected components does not necessarily lead to an optimal solution either. The reason why it seemed promising may be less obvious, but in many cases one can see that swapping edges so as to connect a given subgraph leads to a solution with smaller weight (example: try that on a triangle with one additional edge connected to each vertex; the triangle is one part, the rest is a second, with total weight 3+6=9. Then exchanging two edges gives a path and a star, with total weight 4+4=8.)

I'm currently trying to work out reductions from related problems (see above), as well as other leads suggested by the kind readers of the TCS forum.

Comment: 
Question: is there a partition of $E$ into $|E|/3$ parts such that the sum of the orders of the (nonnecessarily connected) corresponding subgraphs is at most $t$?

I don't really understand the question.  You take a (not necessarily proper) 3-colouring of the edges of $G$, then look at the sum of the orders of the subgraphs defined by the colour classes.  But what is the order of such a subgraph, if it isn't $n$?  Do you mean the set of vertices incident to an edge of the colour?

Comment: The order of the subgraph is the cardinality of its vertex set. As an example, $K_4$ can be (edge-)partitioned into a triangle and a star, whose orders add up to 3+4=7.

Comment: Note, it's an $|E|/3$-edge-colouring, not necessarily proper 

Comment: Anthony: for clarification, is it allowed that some parts are empty? In this case it seems to put all edges in one part is optimal, since it achieves objective $n+0+0+\dotsb$, which is clearly best possible. 

FWIW, I would be a little surprised if the problem has been studied since it's pretty specific and not especially natural (in my opinion). What if instead of $|E|/3$ parts you want $\ell$ parts for some other $\ell$? What is your motivation?

Comment: Dave: no, I want exactly $|E|/3$ parts, each of size $3$, and none can be empty. I agree that the problem is not especially natural, my motivation is that it is a special case of another problem I'm interested in (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13364/consensus-clustering-using-set-union), so hardness of the former would imply hardness of the latter.

Comment: So in other words you want to maximize $A-B-2C$, where $A$ is the number of triangles, $B$ is the number of forests with exactly two components (i.e. five vertices) and $C$ is the number of forests with three components, (i.e. six vertices).

The small number of configurations gives some hope for a polytime algorithm.  I would start looking at combinations, e.g. clearly if you have a matching of size 3 incident to all 3 vertices of a triangle, you can rearrange and gain 1 (as in your prism example).

Comment: You have always $t\geq 7/4$ for connected graphs with at least $4$ vertices with equality if and only if the graph is obtained from a bipartite cubic graph with $n/2$ vertices where we replace each vertex in a bipartite class by a small triangle.

Comment: Does there exist an example where an optimal partition must have partitions inducing non-connected graphs?  The second point in the proposer's statement seems to say "yes", but I have been unable to come up with any examples.  Could it be equivalent to the problem of finding a partition of the edge set into triangles, claws and P_4's maximizing the number of triangles?

Comment: @Anthony: What is a *natural* upper bound? Is being natural crucial?

Comment: @Hans Stricker: simply an upper bound that belongs to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Paul Wollan: see my first point concerning maximising the number of triangles. I have been unable so far to find examples where allowing disconnected components was the only way to get an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the clarifications (the original post did not say each part should have size 3, maybe you can add that). <s>I will take a stab, but it is not very clever so possibly I missed something.</s>

Note,

- for a given triple of edges, its subgraph has $\ge 3$ nodes with equality iff it is a triangle
- thus for a given partition into $|E|/3$ triples, the sum of this over all parts is $\ge |E|$ with equality iff every triple forms a triangle.

However, it is known, due to [Holyer 1981](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/journals/siamcomp/siamcomp10.html#Holyer81), that it's NP-complete to determine whether a graph can be edge-partitioned into triangles. So I think your problem is also NP-complete on these instances (taking $t=|E|$).

RE: your comment, thanks, I forgot it is cubic!

Comment: A cubic graph (and actually, any $k$-regular graph with $k$ odd) cannot be partitioned into triangles. I agree that intuition would suggest that maximizing the number of triangles would be the way to go, but the following counterexample will convince you otherwise: take the complement of a cycle of length 6 (http://wwwteo.informatik.uni-rostock.de/isgci/images/g_co-C6.gif). If you use both triangles, you get a solution of weight 12, while discarding one triangle gives you a solution of weight 11.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing bit, I modified my question accordingly.